# What statistical test do I use to compare two counts with several categories?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I'm trying to figure out how to test if the count of benthic species is significantly different between two transects. We have 13 species in this example, with two transects, each transect having a different % abundance for each species.

What test should I use for this? My knowledge is limited to basic statistics, like f- and t-tests, ANOVA, etc. I apologize if the answer is obvious.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How do you wind up with these numbers ike $69.23$ and $1.72?$

Comment: If you had counts (per your title), I'd have an answer (indeed your title question has been answered multiple times on site already) -- but you only show percentages in your question which presents a problem. Do you have the original counts available? Additionally, if you're presenting data, it would help quite a bit if it was not just an image, from several points of view.

Comment: Presumably your column totals are 78 and 58 or some small integer multiple (like twice those numbers, perhaps), but it would be good to have confirmation. However, if those are your totals, your counts are mostly extremely low, you won't find a difference here (edit: indeed, and exact test based on a chi-squared and the Fisher exact test both give p>0.2 for those column totals)

Comment: @Glen_b yes, I do have counts. My bad. My numbers are indeed 78 and 58, thank you so much! I can do a fisher exact and chi squared with data like this though?

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "data like this"? I presumed you were looking for a test of the null hypothesis of homogeneity of proportions (which is equivalent to testing for independence). Note that I didn't do a a chi-squared test, but rather an exact test *based on the chi-squared statistic*; this is no harder to do than a Fisher exact test. However I also did a Fisher exact test on the same table (you should not use BOTH). Either way, your sample sizes are only not-tiny in one species; you won't find any difference in proportions; (I only found the p-values to show that my claim was the case).

Comment: @Glen_b thank you. I understand now. Yes, that is my null hypothesis. Apologies for being confusing, I was confusing myself as well.

Answer (score 2):

Moving some comments to an answer since we seem to have gotten to the bottom of the situation.

Given the desire to test homogeneity of proportion across transects and given that
your column totals are 78 and 58 (both details being confirmed in comments), we can get back to the counts from the percentages, but your counts are mostly extremely low.

If the assumptions are suitable (which they may well not be; data from transects would reasonably be expected to have spatial dependence), you won't find a difference in proportions across transects here; at the least you'd need several rows with non-tiny row-totals, not just one.

Indeed, an exact test based on a chi-squared statistic or the Fisher exact test would both give $p > 0.2$ here, well above any significance level I imagine you care about. Any other test of the same hypothesis will almost certainly lead to large $p$ values (but don't interpret that as a suggestion to go looking for one that doesn't).